# link correctly against wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

So, 
recently i downloaded the newest version of wxPack (wxWidgets3.0.0) for C++, and installed it. now that i want to use it in my program, i included the "include" path inside the library's base directory, and added the gcc48_lib directory to the library directories. however, i dont quite get which library to link against in order to get my dialog with a single button displayed. ive tried both `libwxmsw30u` and `libwxmsw30u_core`, and with both i get linking errors, here being several undefined references to wxWidget components like several class methods. i already tried searching for this on google, but all i get are tutorials on how to build the actual wxWidgets source code, not how to link against it, so, no valuable information there. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: forgot to add that im using the 32bit version of the TDM-GCC-Compiler under Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

The necessary libraries to link with are described on [this wxWidgets page](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_libs.html).

As you can see, `wxBase` (`libwxbase30u` in your case) is needed always, then `wxCore` for all GUI stuff. The rest is used by certain components only, again described on that page.

There also some other auxiliary libraries like `libwxzlib` or `libwxpngd`, but those should be fairly easy to determine by the names of the missing symbols or their associated functionality you are using (compression, PNG images, ...).

Comment: now the wx* undefined symbols are gone, yet im getting different undefined symbols errors now, which are e.g. `_imp__GetObjectW@12` and `_imp__DeleteObject@4` . ive had these errors before, ppl suggested me that i should link against ole32 or gdi32, ive also tried mingw32, and none of these work. i still get the errors

Comment: OK, that's in GDI32.DLL from Windows - you generally need to link with common Windows libraries. One wxWidgets example I Googled quickly said `-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lwsock32`, that should work for most commonly used APIs.

Comment: im getting the errors in the `wx/thread.h` file, in several wxWidgets functions like `vswscanf`, undefined reference to `__ms_vswscanf`. Library handling in C/C++ SUCKS. :(

Comment: and all the 'deleteObject' / 'createObject' undefined references from gdi32 are still there too.

Comment: compiled it in 64bit with lib64 added now, now im "only" getting 3 undefined reference errors like this: `C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\API\C++\wxWidgets3.0\lib64\gcc48_lib\libwxbase30u.a(baselib_filename.o):filename.cpp|| undefined reference to `IID_IShellLinkW'|` . any idea what that is? `__imp_coCreateInstance` is also an undefined reference.

Comment: CoCreateInstance is in OLE32, IID_IShellLink is SHELL32.

Comment: now: thats strange. i compiled it using the dll version of the libs, and this time, no linking errors.

Comment: somehow, my compiler setup doesnt seem like it wants to link against wxwidgets statically...