# Is it possible to setup the wxWidgets library in Qt creator IDE?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, wxwidgets

Is it possible to setup the `wxWidgets` library in Qt Creator? And what are the steps to do that?  I know the steps in Visual Studio, but Qt creator no, because it is no easy.

I have tried to write the following in `.pro` file.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/wxWidgets302/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/wxWidgets302/lib/gcc_lib/mswu"
LIBS += -L"C:/wxWidgets302/lib/gcc_lib" -lwxbase30u -lwxmsw30u_core -lwxpng -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat
```

but still does not linked, and the following errors appeared.

1. `undefined reference to IID_IShellLinkW`
2. `undefined reference to _imp__CoCreateInstance@20`
3. `undefined reference to IID_IPersistFile`
4. `undefined reference to _imp__OleUninitialize@0`
5. `undefined reference to _imp__OleUninitialize@0`
6. `C:/wxWidgets302/lib/gcc_lib\libwxbase30u.a(baselib_filename.o): bad
   reloc address 0xa in section
   .text$_ZN8wxString4LastEv[__ZN8wxString4LastEv]`
7. `error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I'm using `qtcreator v3.1.2` + `mingw v4.8.2 32Bit` + `wxWidgets v3.0.2`.

Comment: It's clearly possible, you can use either a CMake or a QMake makefile that links the wxWidgets library. It's the same steps as with any other library

Comment: @PeterT: Thanks, but I have tried to do that with QMake in `.pro` file but still does not linked, please I want to know the right steps.

Comment: well, what were the errors?

Comment: @PeterT: I have updated the question, now you can see the errors that I encountered.

Comment: those are missing symbols from Window libraries. Let me check which ones I link to with wx

Comment: But I worry about the last error, did you compile wx yourself, or could it be that the libraries where compiled with an incompatible compiler

Comment: I have compiled the `wxWidget` by using `mingw v4.8.2 32Bit` command prompt as the following: `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release RUNTIME_LIBS=static MONOLITHIC=0 SHARED=0 UNICODE=1`.

Comment: I'm linking to `"odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "comctl32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "shlwapi.lib" "winmm.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib"` but the errors seem to reference mainly `"shlwapi.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib"`, so try linking only those at first

Comment: @PeterT: When add the libraries `shlwapi.lib`, `shell32.lib`,  `ole32.lib` like ex: `LIBS += -L"C:/wxWidgets302/lib/gcc_lib" shlwapi.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib -lwxbase30u -lwxmsw30u_core -lwxpng -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat`, give me an error  `error: shlwapi.lib: No such file or directory`. the previous error message repeated with three libs.

Comment: you might need to add the directory of the Windows SDK to the linker search paths

Comment: or as a comment in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495303/link-correctly-against-wxwidgets suggests use `-lshell32` and the like, and maybe omit shlwapi, maybe shell32 is enough, you might try the list posted in the comments to the linked question if there's more symbols then

Comment: @PeterT: Notice that I'm not installed the Windows SDK in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code in your pro file:

```
wxCXXFLAGS = $$system(wx-config --cxxflags --unicode=yes --debug=no)
wxLinkOptions = $$system(wx-config --debug=no --libs --unicode=yes)
LIBS += $$wxLinkOptions
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += $$wxCXXFLAGS
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += $$wxCXXFLAGS
```