# How to properly compile a basic wxWidgets program

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile a wxWidgets application using MinGW on windows, but i will always get undefined errors (i am new to c++ programming so i don't really know what i am doing), so i just want to know how to compile it right withnout any issues/errors.

The latest command i tried is

```
g++ noname.cpp -I ".\wxWidgets-3.1.5\include" -I ".\wxWidgets-3.1.5\include\wx\msw" -I ".\wxWidgets-3.1.5\build\lib\wx\include\msw-unicode-3.1" -I ".\wxWidgets-3.1.5\include\msvc"
```

and i keep getting a very long log of undefined errors (its too long so i can't paste it)

I just want it to work withnout any issues, so the question is **how do i correctly compile a simple wxWidgets app using MinGW on windows?**

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: At the very least, post the first few errors you're getting. We can't help if we don't know what the problems are.

Comment: @dalkom12, how did you compile the library (wxWidgets)?

Comment: You can also use an IDE (MSVC, CodeBlocks, CodeLite) to successfully builddebug and run the wxWidgets-based binary. What seems to be the problem?.

Comment: Looks like you are not linking any of the wxWidgets libraries. This question may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495303/link-correctly-against-wxwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495303/link-correctly-against-wxwidgets)

Comment: @jkb i don't remember all the errors, but now i am getting  `undefined reference to \`WinMain'` with the command `g++ noname.cpp -I ".\wxWidgets-3.1.5\include" -I ".\wxWidgets-3.1.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu" -L ".\wxWidgets-3.1.5\lib\gcc_dll" -l wxbase31u -l wxmsw31u_core`

Comment: @Igor i tried recompiling it by following [this tutorial](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW), it did fix a few errors but i still keep getting a `undefined reference to \`WinMain'` error when i try to compile

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, i did some research and it worked

Comment: @dalkom12, did you use`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release`? If that worked - try to do this: `cd `wxWidgets\samples\minimal && mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release && ./minimal.exe`. That should work - adjust the directory path if needed. Then check the command used to build the sample and use it to compile you code.

Comment: @Igor it did work for the minimal sample, but i don't have a makefile though.

Comment: @dalkom12,, you don't have to have Makefile. Look at the build log and issue the same commands that is made to build `minimal` sample. Just use you own cpp files.

Comment: @Igor thank you very much, this finally worked. Also, is there a way to statically link the libraries? When i try to do so with the minimal sample (by changing "shared" to 0), it gives me an error: `wx/setup.h: No such file or directory`. Also, the command from the build log is using some of the .o files from the minimal sample, so i can't use it on my code.

Comment: @dalkom12, You should start with building wxWidgets with the `SHARED=0` option. And then build the minimal sample with the same options set. You can also drop the `UNICODE=1` option as this is now default setting. So the command to build will be just `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=0 BUILD=release/debug`. You will need to build both debug and release versions, hence the command for both. And then after this is done use exactly the same command for minimal sample.

Comment: @dalkom12, and then use the same command for the software you are working on. (as before). And I'm not sure what you meant by your last sentence. Just give that command in the directory of your software. You don't need any .o files anywhere. It will compile all.cpp files and produce the executable.

Comment: @Igor thank you very much, i finally compiled it withnout any issues :)

Comment: @dalkom12, np. that's why we are here. ;-)